# Php - Laravel with MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, connection

Hey there i tried to setup the laravel-framework locally.

So i installed laravel and mamp => worked.

Next i configured database-settings:

Mamp:

1. Host: localhost
2. User: root
3. Password: root

Next i created database in mamp-phpmyadmin, name: laravel_app

All i did in laravel is, i edited ".env" in root directory of my laravel-app:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=secret_app_key

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel_app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

When i try to run migrate:install:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

i get:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in /Users/my_computer/laravel_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47 etc..
```

But what is wrong now? 
Anybody could help with this?

Greetings and thanks!!

Comment: Did you try switching from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in your Laravel config?

Answer (score 0):

Check the current version MAMP. Say you 5.6.10

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Make sure that you export the same version of php

```
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin
```

Good luck =)